Is my proof that $X \setminus (Y\cup Z)=(X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$ valid?
Currently studying the first chapter of Munkre's Topology, and I'm enjoying time spent proving statements. I am trying to prove De Morgan's laws. I am worried that this proof is not valid, specifically in the logical jumps such as "If $a\notin (Y\cup Z)$ then $a\notin Y$ and $a\notin Z$." To obtain that implication I used combinations of $a\in Y$, $a\in Z$, $a\notin Y$ or $a\notin Z$ and got
$$a\in Y\lor a\in Z \Rightarrow a\in (Y \cup Z)$$
$$a\notin Y\land a\notin Z \Rightarrow a\notin (Y\cup Z)$$
Then an part of this question is: Should that process be outlined in the proof?
Overall: Is the following proof valid? This proof is left as an exercise in the main text body.
Theorem. Let $X,Y,Z$ be sets. Then $X \setminus (Y\cup Z)=(X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$.
Proof. If $a\in X\setminus (Y\cup Z)$ then $a\in X$ and $a\notin (Y\cup Z)$. If $a\notin (Y\cup Z)$ then $a\notin Y$ and $a\notin Z$. Then if $a\in  X\setminus (Y\cup Z)$ then $a\in X$ and $a\notin Y$ and $a\notin Z$.
If $a\in (X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$ then $a\in (X\setminus Y)$ and $a\in (X\setminus Z)$. If $a\in (X\setminus Y)$ then $a\in X$ and $a\notin Y$. If $a\in (X\setminus Z)$ then $a\in X$ and $a\notin Z$. Then if $a\in (X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$ then $a\in X$ and $a\notin Y$ and $a\notin Z$.
Then if $a\in X\setminus (Y\cup Z)$ then $a\in (X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$ and if $a\in (X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$ then $a\in X\setminus (Y\cup Z)$. Then $a\in X\setminus (Y\cup Z)$ iff $a\in (X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$. Then, using the axiom of extension, $X \setminus (Y\cup Z)=(X\setminus Y)\cap (X \setminus Z)$. $\square$

Sometimes instead of your third paragraph we'll note the first paragraph proves $X \setminus (Y \cup Z) \subseteq (X \setminus Y) \cap (X \setminus Z)$ and the second paragraph proves $(X \setminus Y) \cap (X \setminus Z) \subseteq X \setminus (Y \cup Z)$, therefore $X \setminus (Y \cup Z) = (X \setminus Y) \cap (X \setminus Z)$. If you don't already have it, $(A \subseteq B) \land (B \subseteq A) \Rightarrow A=B$ is a very easy theorem.

Yes $(A\subset B)\land (B\subset A) \implies A=B$ is a useful theorem. I often use biconditional introduction in this sort of proof: $(p\implies q)\land (q\implies p):=(p\iff q)$. I suppose that this is equivalent because $A\subset B:= [x\in A\implies x\in B]$. I find the proof I wrote in the question quite convoluted, and I have answered my own question below using a string of statements connected by biconditional implication.

Theorem. $R\setminus (S\cap T)=(R\setminus S)\cup (R\setminus T)$ for all sets $R,S,T$.
Proof.
$x\in R\setminus (S\cap T)$
$\iff (x\in R) \land (x\notin S\cap T)$
$\iff (x\in R)\land (x\notin S \lor x\notin T)$
$\iff (x\in R \land x\notin S)\lor (x\in R \land x\notin T)$
$\iff (x\in R\setminus S) \lor (x\in R\setminus T)$
$\iff x\in (R\setminus S)\cup (R\setminus T)$.
$\implies R\setminus (S\cap T)=(R\setminus S)\cup (R\setminus T).$ $\square$

You are on the right track! Well done!
However, if I were you, I would stress out that $a\in X$ and $a\not\in Y$ and $a\not\in Z$ implies $a\in X\backslash Y$ and $a\in X\backslash Z$. Similar observation applies to the reverse relation, that is to say, $a\in X$ and $a\not\in Y$ and $a\not\in Z$ implies that $a\in X\backslash(Y\cup Z)$.
Here is another way to approach it:
\begin{align*}
X\backslash(Y\cup Z) & = X\cap(Y\cup Z)^{c} \tag{Definition of Difference}\\\\
& = X\cap (Y^{c}\cap Z^{c}) \tag{DeMorgan's Law}\\\\
& = (X\cap X)\cap(Y^{c}\cap Z^{c}) \tag{Idempotence}\\\\
& = X\cap (X\cap(Y^{c}\cap Z^{c})) \tag{Associativity}\\\\
& = X\cap ((X\cap Y^{c})\cap Z^{c}) \tag{Associativity}\\\\\
& = (X\cap(X\cap Y^{c}))\cap Z^{c} \tag{Associativity}\\\\
& = ((X\cap Y^{c})\cap X)\cap Z^{c} \tag{Commutativity}\\\\
& = (X\cap Y^{c})\cap (X\cap Z^{c}) \tag{Associativity}\\\\
& = (X\backslash Y)\cap(X\backslash Z) \tag{Definition of Difference}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

Thank you. I will apply your feedback to my proof and study your proof, which is done in quite a different style that I hadn’t considered.

@WillFitchet you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Use of $A^c$ implies a contextual universe set. The theorem can be proved without one.
